# React useeffect hook behaving not like i expected

Tags: reactjs, use-effect

I am using react `useEffect` hook to fetch data from my firestore database. I realised that when I change my firestore database data manually from google console panel, `useEffect` runs and updates the document altough I made the second parameter of `useEffect` [], Dont get me wrong this is what i want from it but not what i expected because as far as i know useeeffect runs only when the second parameter changes after its first run. So can someone explain me what is going on here?

Here is my code:

```
import React, {useState,useEffect, useRef, useContext} from 'react'
import fire from '../config/Fire';
import UserContext from  './UserContext.js';
import '../App.css';
let myvar1="";
let myvar2=""; 

function useTimes(){
    const user = useContext(UserContext)
    const [kullanici,setTimes] = useState([])
    useEffect(()=>{
      fire
        .firestore()
        .collection('kullanici')
        .doc(user)
        .onSnapshot((doc)=>{
            const newTimes = doc.data()
            setTimes(newTimes)
        })
    },[])

    return kullanici
}
function useInterval(callback, delay) {
    const savedCallback = useRef();
  
    // Remember the latest callback.
    useEffect(() => {
      savedCallback.current = callback;
    }, [callback]);
  
    // Set up the interval.
    useEffect(() => {
      function tick() {
        savedCallback.current();
      }
      if (delay !== null) {
        let id = setInterval(tick, delay);
        return () => clearInterval(id);
      }
    }, [delay]);
  }

const Main = () => {
  //console.log(firebase.auth().currentUser.uid)
    useInterval(() => {
        // Your custom logic here
        setCount(count + 1);
    }, 1000);

    const kullanici =useTimes()
    let [count, setCount] = useState(0);
    let currenttime =new Date().getTime();
    let irondec = (currenttime-kullanici.irondate)/1000
    let silverdec = (currenttime-kullanici.silverdate)/1000
    let copperdec = (currenttime-kullanici.copperdate)/1000
    let golddec = (currenttime-kullanici.golddate)/1000
    let oildec = (currenttime-kullanici.oildate)/1000
    let wooddec = (currenttime-kullanici.wooddate)/1000
    let iron_real= Math.trunc((irondec*kullanici.iron)+kullanici.ironvalue);
    let silver_real= Math.trunc((silverdec*kullanici.silver)+kullanici.silvervalue);
    let copper_real= Math.trunc((copperdec*kullanici.copper)+kullanici.coppervalue);
    let wood_real= Math.trunc((wooddec*kullanici.wood)+kullanici.woodvalue);
    let gold_real= Math.trunc((golddec*kullanici.gold)+kullanici.goldvalue);
    let oil_real= Math.trunc((oildec*kullanici.oil)+kullanici.oilvalue);
    let sonuciron = iron_real;
    let sonucsilver = silver_real;
    let sonuccopper = copper_real;
    let sonucwood = wood_real;
    let sonucoil = oil_real;
    let sonucgold = gold_real;
    return(
      <div>
        <div>
        <ul className="a">
        <li>Silver: <span>{kullanici.silvervalue ? sonucsilver : 'You have no mines, Build Mines'} </span></li>
        <li>Copper: <span>{kullanici.coppervalue ? sonuccopper : 'You have no mines, Build Mines'} </span></li>
        <li>Iron: <span>{kullanici.ironvalue ?  sonuciron : 'You have no mines, Build Mines'} </span></li>
        <li>Wood: <span>{kullanici.woodvalue ? sonucwood : 'You have no mines, Build Mines'} </span></li>
        <li>Gold: <span>{kullanici.goldvalue ? sonucgold : 'You have no mines, Build Mines'} </span></li>
        <li>Oil: <span>{kullanici.oilvalue ?  sonucoil : 'You have no mines, Build Mines'} </span></li>
        <li>Account: <span>{kullanici.email} </span></li>
        </ul>
        </div>
        </div>
    )
  }


export default Main
```

Comment: I deleted my answer, I think there were some problems with it. I think your issue is more about how you're modifying things from the console.

Comment: i am modifying the exact document values i list here, changing values in the document. As soon as i change, my changes affect the react component.

Comment: have you tried to use `get` method instead `onSnapshot`, maybe this could fix the issue you are heading

Comment: @RicardoGonzalez no i didnt, but can onSnapshot method change values although useeffect dont run?

Comment: As i understand i think that one of the `onSnapshot` use cases is to the data always updated , check the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen) if you are still have questions. Ive run into this issue and with this little hack i solved the unnesessaty updates on `useEffect`.